# How do I prove that $161616 \dots 16$ ($100$ digits) cannot be written as a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I did:
$$
16 \cdot 101010 \dots 1 \quad (99 \text{ digits}) 
$$

It's clear that $16 = 2^4$, satisfying the condition that the prime has to have an even power. But what about $101010 \dots 1$?

Also, I tried $16 \pmod 4$ but it's congruent to $0$.

(???)

Comment: *Hint:* calculate the number mod $9$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Consider the $161616\ldots 16$ ($100$ digits) number (or, since the $16$ factor is a perfect square, the $101010\ldots 1$ ($99$ digits) number) in modulo $9$, using that the sum of digits has the same remainder as the value when divided by $9$, to get that it's not one of the possible congruences of $\{0,1,4,7\}$ modulo $9$ of perfect squares.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $1616\dots 16$ ($100$ digits) is a perfect square, so is $101010\dots 101$ ($99$ digits), since $16$ is a perfect square. Now consider the latter number: is it $\equiv 1 \pmod 8$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have reputation to comment, Hence, suggesting here.

- if a positive integer n is a perfect square then n can not be written in form of 4k+3, for k is an integer.
- Square of an integer leaves reminder 0 or 1 upon division by 4.
- More importantly , the square of any integer is either of the form 3k or 3k+1. In this case n= 16....16 (100 digit) , leaves 2 as remainder when divided by 3.  ${n = 2 (mod 3)}$, hence it doesn't seem a perfect square.
- This means no square can be written in form of ${3k+2}$, why? proof... By Division Algorithm every integer can be written in form of ${3k, 3k+1}$ or ${3k+2}$. if ${n=3k}$ then ${n^2}$ also of this form. if ${n=3k+1}$ then ${n^2=3K+1}$, where ${K=3k^2+2k}$ But if ${n=3k+2}$ then ${n^2=3K+1}$ where ${K=3k^2+4k+1}$, we've ${n}$ in form of ${3k+2}$ ..so, it can't be perfect square !

Comment: This means no square can be written in form of 3k+2, why? proof...

By Division Algorithm every integer can be written in form of 3k, 3k+1 and 3k+2.
if ${n=3k}$ then ${n^2}$ also of this form.
if ${n=3k+1}$ then ${n^2 =3K+1}$, where ${K=3k^2+2k}$
But if ${n=3k+2}$ then ${n^2 =3K+1}$ where ${K=3k^2+4k+1}$,  we've n in form of ${3k+2}$ ..so, it can't be perfect square !

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can cast out $9$s, you can also cast out $99$s.

Suppose we can write $N^2 = 161616\dots 16$. Where $16$ occurs $50$ times.

Casting out $99$s, you get

$$N^2 \equiv 16 + 16 +\dots + 16 \equiv 50\cdot 16 \equiv  800 
      \equiv 8 + 00 \equiv8 \pmod {99}$$

This implies $N^2 \equiv 8 \pmod 9$, which has no solution.

\begin{array}{c|c}
 N \mod 9 & N^2 \mod 9 \\
\hline
 0    & 0 \\
 1, 8 & 1 \\
 2, 7 & 4 \\
 3, 6 & 0 \\
 4, 5 & 7 \\
\hline
\end{array}